# Django comments deletion

Tags: python, django

I am having challenges in getting user comment deletion functionality for my django blog.
The logic is as follows:

- user who made a comment under blog post and is logged in will see Delete button next to their comment
- once the user click on delete comment button they are taken to Comment_confirm_delete page to confirm deletion

Below is what I have:

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

STATUS = ((0, "Draft"), (1, "Published"))

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_likes', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

class Comment(models.Model):
    
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment {self.body} by {self.name}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'comment': id})
```

urls.py

```
from . import views 
from .views import CommentDeleteView
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.PostList.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('like/<slug:slug>', views.PostLike.as_view(), name='post_like'),
    path('delete/<comment_id>', views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment_confirm_delete')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.views import generic, View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import CommentForm


class PostList(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 4


class PostDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by("-created_on")
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        return render(
            request,
            "post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": False,
                "liked": liked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm()
            },
        )

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
        post = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        comments = post.comments.filter(approved=True).order_by("-created_on")
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment_form.instance.email = request.user.email
            comment_form.instance.name = request.user.username
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        return render(
            request,
            "post_detail.html",
            {
                "post": post,
                "comments": comments,
                "commented": True,
                "liked": liked,
                "comment_form": CommentForm()
            },
        )

class PostLike(View):

    def post(self, request, slug):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[slug]))


class CommentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_confirm_delete.html'
    success_url = "/"

    def test_func(self, comment_id):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.name:
            return render(request, "comment_confirm_delete.html")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[slug]))
```

post_detail.html

```
                    <!-- The body of the comment goes before the | -->
                    {{ comment.body | linebreaks }}
                        {%  if user.username == comment.name %}

                        <a href="{% url 'comment_confirm_delete' comment.id %}"i class="fas fa-trash"> 
                        Delete</a>
```

I am looking for advice and specific comments as to what needs to be corrected in terms of the structure.
At the moment I am getting error : Generic detail view CommentDeleteView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your comment deletion url path to:

```
path('delete/<int:pk>', views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment_confirm_delete')
```

and correct your `test_func` method:

```
class CommentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    ...
    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.username == comment.name:
            return True
        return False
```

PS think about storing `User` that commented with `ForeignKey`, because if that user would change his `username` and some other user would change to the first one's, then the other user will be able to delete it. `Charfield` is definitely bad approach to that.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. This did not work unfortunately as this getting errors

Comment: @adam ok, I've edited my answer, cause you also used `test_func` wrongly.